# Using String.split with a regex

Tags: java, regex

...so I'm trying to split data using the split() method of string.  (And by the way, I'm impressed with how well regular expressions have evolved in Java since I last bent code in a serious fashion.)

Here's what I'm trying, and it doesn't seem to give me results I would predict:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "CSCO_9910290";

    String [] ss = s.split("(.*)_(.*)"); // split on the _ character
    System.out.println("Size of ss is: " + ss.length + "\n"); // this prints 0

    for (String r : ss ){
        System.out.println("result is: " + r + "\n");
    }
    System.out.println("Finished now..."); // declares completion of loop

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the regular expression for `split`, the aim is not to create a regular expression for the entire string, but for matching the separator(s) only.  You don't need anything but:

```
String [] ss = s.split("_");
```

Comment: ...of course. Blame it on an aging Perl programmer. (not me of course, I'm never to blame.)

Answer (score 1):

```
String [] ss = s.split("_"); // split on the _ character
```

It is the correct way.

Comment: ...actually, now that makes sense to me. I was working too hard.

Answer (score 1):

For splitting on the `_` character simply use `s.split("_")`